# Can I name SQL's result columns with camel-case aliases?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How can I name SQL's result columns with camel-case aliases?
I am interested to use it for MySQL and Oracle 10g/11g.

Comment: Put the aliases in double quotes.

Comment: At least in Oracle, you can Quote the aliases. `select some_column as "SomeColumn"...` Don't know about mysql.

Comment: MySQL uses back-ticks `"`"`.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. You are entering a world of hurt here when working with tools that interact with Oracle, reporting. web services, applications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shannon Severance suggested:

> At least in Oracle, you can Quote the aliases. select some_column as
>   "SomeColumn"

and as for MySQL - it simply uses provided column names without pre-capitalizing them. The same is true for aliases. Result of 
`SELECT customerName ... from ...` 
 will have column with exactly the same name in camel-case.